# Is it possible to convert USB 2.0 into USB 3.0?

Tags: usb

Are the connection pins the only thing that differs between the two? Or do other major compatibility issues lie within the lines, cables, and software as well?

Comment: Do you mean to modify a USB 2.0 device to transfer data at USB 3.0 rates?

Comment: Yes, whether that be physically replacing parts or various other alterations/modifications that would achieve the same goal.

Comment: This is similar to the conversion process for Mazda to Porsche, with less welding.

Comment: No. &nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: &nbsp; will count as a character in your answer. Helps you reach those pesky 30 char mins. :) &nbsp;

Comment: You can convert USB2.0 into light but it wont make USB2.0 any faster.

Comment: So, this is a bad question? I guess all the down votes are worth the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. By replacing the entire usb controller in the device. And the circuit board. And the firmware.

In other words, no. USB 3.0 is not a drop in replacement for USB 2.0.

Now if you need to connect a USB 2.0 device to a USB 3.0 Host, there are two options. The first is a direct connection. 3.0 is backwards compatible, so it can read 2.0 devices at 2.0 speeds. The other option is using a 3.0 hub. USB has Transaction Translators, which can take a slower downstream USB device packets, and interleave them at 3.0 speeds, upstream. Of course, the bottleneck will still exist, it can't magically speed a device up, but it allows a hub to not slow down on it's upstream connection, if you mix usb 1.1, usb 2.0 and usb 3.0 downstream.

Comment: I expect this assumes a hub with a USB3 upstream port?

Comment: @PeterBennett yes. Clarified.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect.  As far as I've been able to find, there is no transaction translation between USB 2.0 and 3.0.  Only 1.1 and 2.0.  See also:  https://superuser.com/a/624312/48624  If you know of a device that actually works in the mode you are describing, could you post a link?

Answer (score 3):

The thread may be old, but for people who come here through google: I think, the VL670 by VIA Labs may be what you're looking for. (Evaluation boards are sold on the manufacturer's website) They say that this will not work for every device though... 
Another solution is using usb over IP, and use an usb3 <-> ethernet adapter, then plug an usb2 over IP adapter in the eth port.